# Como recortar una cadena string en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy usando la clase de `WebRequest` para obtener el codigo `html` de una página en especifico, el resultado me lo arroja en una varible tipo string pero necesito acceder a su contenido.

¿Saben con qué funcion puedo recortar la cadena y que solo quede el texto que deseo ?

Comment: Existen muchas maneras de manipular un string, necesitas ser más específico.  Incluye un ejemplo pequeño de la cadena que tienes y la que quieres obtener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas trabajando con `html` a paesar que la respuesta la obtengas en un string, para trabajar con esa informacion debes usar uan libreria que permita entender los `tags` html y poder acceder a los valores de los nodos y sus atributos.

Recomiendo use la libreria

[Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

la puedes referencia por nuget

[HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)

La idea es que teniendo el string puedas parsear el `html` usando selectores, similar a como harias con un `xml`

Analiza los ejemplos de la documentacion de la liberia, pero veras que simple lo realiza

```
var html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>This is <b>bold</b> heading</h1>
    <p>This is <u>underlined</u> paragraph</p>
    <h2>This is <i>italic</i> heading</h2>
</body>
</html> ";

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

Console.WriteLine(htmlBody.OuterHtml);
```

teniendo un html en un string puedes acceder al contenido del body, o puedes seleccionar un nodo

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/input");
```

Comment: Lo voy a probar, muchas gracias!